# How to show [Add this sharing buttons] in Blog page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, addthis

I'm using:
Wordpress4.1.1
DW Timeline Pro 1.0.7
AddThis Sharing Buttons 5.2.0

I can see the sharing buttons in the each post:
[image: Sharing buttons in a post]

But I can not see the sharing buttons in the timeline:
[image: No sharing buttons in timeline]

What I want is to show the sharing buttons in the timeline so that the readers can share the post without having to click the post
[image]

I know I might need to change some php files but do not know which files to go, hope someone can help, thanks :)

Comment: you have one plugin ?